# Pythonic way of searching a dict of lists?

Tags: python, list, algorithm, dictionary

I like to use the 'dict-of-lists' structure to organize data in Python for various reasons, however, a drawback I've found is it can be annoying to perform lookups.

Take an example where the data is the history of NCAA tournament finals--it would be something like:

```
    data = {'year': ['2019','2018',...],'winner': ['Virginia','Villanova',...], 'score':[]...etc}
```

Now suppose I wanted to find data on all the years that UConn won, as of now the way I do that is:

```
    columns = ['year','winner','coach','score','runner_up'] 
    new_dict = {i: [] for i in columns}                      #redefine blank dict
    for i in range(0,len(old_dict['year']),1):               #go through range
        for j in columns:                                    #go through columns
            if old_dict['winner'][i]=='Connecticut':
                new_dict[j].append(old_dict[j][i])           #append chosen data to new dict

    ....new_dict = {'year': ['2014','2011',...],'winner': ['Connecticut','Connecticut',...]..etc}
```

Is there any way to do this better? It feels kind of cumbersome and ugly. I've tried stuff with list/dict comprehension but am struggling. Since this type of situation will come up rarely in the projects I do I'd prefer to use generic Python and am not sure something more apt for the job like Pandas/Numpy is worth it.

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you create new dict if you want a list as a result?

Comment: How about changing your data structure to a `list` of `dict` where each `dict` has keys as defined in your `column` variable, in that way lookup would be pretty easy

Comment: Seems to me a list-of-dicts might be a better organization.  `data = [{'year': 2019, 'winner': 'Connecticut', ...}, {'year': 2018, 'winner': 'Villanova', ...}]`

Comment: @JohnGordon yeah but I almost always have dicts-of-lists for inserting into a database, also it's way easier to debug when you can just print lists like you'd see in Excel or SQL results...i don't like seeing the keys for every row lol

Comment: maybe if you'd use less cumbersome structure of the data, for example like @JohnGordon suggests, you'd spend less time debugging, since it would be easier to work with the data, so you wouldn't need to worry how the data during debugging look like.

Answer (score 0):

The code that you are writing is re-creating a relational database, badly.

If you're going to be accessing your data along one pattern only, use a nested data structure that supports that access pattern.  For two access patterns, either transform your data structure or maintain two nested data structures with a wrapper and logic to keep them synchronized.  By the time you get to 3 or more access patterns, use a relational database.

If you want to keep it lightweight, just `db = sqlite3.connect("file::memory:?cache=shared")` to create an in memory SQLite database, and then work with that.